# Using Perl ? bind inside single quotes

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

This scripts works fine for all commands that don't require % wildcards. When I attempt to wrap the ? in %?% which producing a bind error. Also I have tried adding %value% to the argument when running the script and it also producing the same error. Is there a way to substitue an argument into a SQL DBI command in perl?

Thanks, in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use Text::Diff;
use File::stat;
use Fcntl ':flock';

open (LOCK_FH, $0) || die "$0 for lock: $!\n";
flock (LOCK_FH, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB) || die "$0 already running\n";

$BINDVAR = $ARGV[0];
$dbname = "COnnectionDetailsHere";
$un = "username";
$pw = "password";

my $dbh = DBI->connect ( $dbname, $un, $pw, { PrintError=>1, RaiseError=>1, AutoCommit=>0, LongReadLen=>5056}) or die "Couldn't connect to DB: " . DBI->errstr;

$sql = <<SQL

select * from foo where bar like '%?%' '?'

SQL
;

$stm = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die "SQL failed to prepare $DBI::errstr\n";

$stm->bind_param(1,($BINDVAR));

$stm->execute() or die "Couldn't execute the statement: " . $stm->errstr;
```

Comment: Better giving us the exact error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `%` into the variable and *don't put quotes around the* `?`.  That's what's screwing you up - the quotes turn it into a literal question mark.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:');
$dbh->do('CREATE TABLE foo ( bar text )');
$dbh->do(q(INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('xyzzy')));

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE ?');
$sth->execute('%');

print $sth->fetchrow_array . "\n";
```

Output:

```
$ ~/src/tmp/like_qry 
xyzzy
```

Comment: Thats worked. I thought I tried that before. Odd. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 4):

It's not adding the `%` that cause the problem, it's adding the quotes. `?` is a placeholder. `'?'` is a string literal that evaluates to a question mark.

The previous answer effectively suggested you move  the concatenation to the Perl side.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE ?');
$sth->execute('%' . $something . '%');
```

You can keep doing it in the server by using the correct syntax.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE '%' || ? || '%'});
$sth->execute($something);
```

but there's no benefit of that and it risks using [incompatible](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/non-typed-operators.html) [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190301.aspx).

Comment: Is there a benefit to doing it server side?

Comment: @Schwern, Not that I know of. It's what the OP was attempting, so I showed him how.

Comment: I can think of a downside: I don't think that syntax is supported by a lot of servers, even if it is the official SQL concatenation operator.  [MySQL doesn't](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/non-typed-operators.html) unless you're in ANSI mode.  Looks like [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190301.aspx) doesn't.  [PostgreSQL does](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL), but with a caveat.

Comment: @Schwern, Use the syntax appropriate to your server.

Comment: Providing the caveats, and in SQL incompatibility is *always* a caveat, is all part of providing a complete, expert answer.

Comment: @Schwern, Freel free to edit. You know more than I do about this.